# How do you change the color of a package in Eclipse on error instead of marking with the red X?

Tags: eclipse

In Eclipse, when there is an error in a file you get a little red x annotation to show which package the file is in (for Java development.) When you have a large number of packages, small text, and imperfect eyesight it is sometimes difficult to scroll through and see that annotation.

If possible, I'd like to be able to configure Eclipse to change the color of the package name text to make the error location much more apparent.

I've done a lot of searching and I either don't have the correct terms or no one else has wanted to do this as I've not found any solutions to try to resolve this.

Comment: I don't think that is possible. There is also the Problems view which shows just the error messages.